# Better way of finding combination for 3 boolean variables

Tags: boolean-logic

I have 3 bool variables x,y,z. Now at any given moment I can have one out of 2^3=8 combinations as below.

e.g. x=true, y=false and z=false or
x=false, y=true and z=true  and so on.

If I see from programming perspective there are 8 cases or may be 8 or greater if else statement to determine what is the combination at that moment.
At any given moment if I want to know what combination is present(given the values of x,y,z) How can I know without using if-else ladder, which makes code logic little bulky. Is there any better/simple logic/way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must handle 8 situations separately. You could encode the value of x, y, z in a variable and then do a switch case on that variable. Pseudo code below -

```
v = 0
if (x) { v += 4 }
if (y) { v += 2 }
if (z) { v += 1 }

switch (v)
{
  case 0 : // all false
  case 1 : // z is true
  case 2 : // y is true
  case 3 : // z and y are true
  case 4 : // x is true
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vinayak; this seems to be a better and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

It might be worth using bitwise operators, rather than the numeric value to determine which boolean variables are on or off.

```
// Assign the bitwise value of each variable
X = 4
Y = 2
Z = 1

// Setting X and Z as true using the bitwise OR operator.
v = X | Z // v = 4 + 1 = 5

// Checking if any of the variables are true using the bitwise OR operator
if (v | X+Y+Z) // v = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7

// Checking if ALL of the variables are true using the bitwise AND operator
if (v & X+Y+Z)

// Checking if variable Y is true using the bitwise OR operator
if (v | Y)

// Checking if variable Y is false using the bitwise OR operator
if (v | Y == false)

// Checking if ONLY variable Y is true using the bitwise AND operator
if (v & Y)

// Checking if ONLY variable Y is false using the bitwise AND operator
if (v & Y == false)
```

This saves you from messing up the resulting number of a combination of values X, Y, Z. It is also more readable.